# UDP Source port different on client getsocketname() and server recv()

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, winsock, ports

Hi my question is simple:

I try to establish an UDP connection via a TCP connection (Because multiple clients are connected via multiple channels to the server and I want to identifiy same clients via the main TCP connection)

I did this by creating a TCP and UDP Socket on the client and transmit the local UDP port assigned randomly by the OS via TCP to the server. (On Windows I get the port after sendto() via getsocketname()).
On the server I use this port to send UDP packets to this exact client.
Unfortunately the port i really have to send to is different to the local port i sent to the server.

For example:

My Client gets a local UDP port 56423 assigned. Sends it to my Server via the established TCP connection. Server tries to send UDP Packets to that port -> Failed. 
When i use the standard way of retreiving the port on the server via recv() on the UDP socket it reports a source port of 30299. (I have to send UDP packets in advance for that info, but I want to avoid implementing a UDP connection handshake)

How can this be?

To my understanding UDP just has a destination port and a source port. So it should work by sending the client local port to the server. 
Can there possibly be proxy services inbetween that use alternate ports?

Edit:
Some code:

On the client:
(s32 = int, c8 = char)

```
if(m_WinSock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    return;

struct sockaddr_storage addr;
s32 len = sizeof(sockaddr);

getsockname(m_WinSock, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &len);
c8 ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN + 1];
s32 port;
if(addr.ss_family == AF_INET)
{
    struct sockaddr_in *s = (struct sockaddr_in *)&addr;
    m_uLocalPort = ntohs(s->sin_port);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &s->sin_addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
}
else
{ // AF_INET6
    struct sockaddr_in6 *s = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)&addr;
    m_uLocalPort = ntohs(s->sin6_port);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &s->sin6_addr, ipstr, sizeof ipstr);
}
```

m_uLocalPort is transmitted via TCP after that.

On the server:

```
    SOCKADDR_IN address;
    ZeroMemory(&address, sizeof(address));
    address.sin_addr = addrin;
    address.sin_port = htons((u16)remoteport);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
```

remoteport is the port sent by the client.

Using this code on the server after sending a packet from the client:

```
struct sockaddr_storage addr;
s32 len = sizeof(sockaddr);
s32 bytes = recvfrom(m_WinSock, m_RecvBuffer, NET_MAX_UDP_SIZE, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &len);
m_RecvAddress = *(struct sockaddr_in *)&addr;

s32 port = ntohs(m_RecvAddress.sin_port);
printf("recv from port %i\n", port);
```

I receive a totally different port.

Comment: *How* are you sending and receiving the UDP port? Do you forget a `htons`/`ntohs` somewhere? Is the port `30299` (in your example) the TCP connection source or destination port?

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be simpler if the server had a fixed port number, and the client just use the server address and the fixed port number in `sendto`?

Comment: I send the port via a working TCP connection established first. The server has a fixed port number (via bind()) the client sends to. I used htons / ntohs the way it should be i guess. It changes only the byte order but byte order is not the problem, look at the bytes of 56423 and 30299 they differ completely. On the server I want to send UDP pakets to the correct client. To do that i need the client's (random) UDP port. The ports are definately these of the UDP socket. I can see in my Taskmanager that these are bound to my application as UDP listen ports

Comment: Again, *how* are you sending the port number? Please show some code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I edited my Question

Comment: A few more questions for clarification: On the client-side, is `m_WinSock` the UDP socket? Do you call `getsockname` directly after creating the socket (because that won't work, you either need to `bind` the socket or call `sendto`)? You should really check if `getsockname` succeeds or not. Then on the server side, is `m_WinSock` the UDP socket? How would you expect to receive on that when the client send a TCP message to the TCP socket? And you still haven't shown *how* you send or receive the TCP message containing the UDP port information (even if that information is wrong).

Comment: Yes m_WinSock is the UDP socket. I did not post the code where I implicitly bind the socket with sendto, but I send an initial "hi" to get a port and after that I call getsockname, I read all the docs ;)

Comment: You send your `"hi"` message *where*? Have you checked that *that* call doesn't fail? And excuse me for being repetitive, but I still don't understand how you actually send the UDP port number from the client to the server. Is the server receiving this `"hi"` message and you get the client port number from that? Then why do you need to send the port-number in the first place, just use the address structure that was filled in by `recvfrom` in the servers `sendto` calls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84931/discussion-between-ecreif-and-joachim-pileborg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a reliable approach for the problem. For example, NAT can get in the way and remap your port or even the local ip seen from your client. You may also need to do udp hole punching.

The proper way is not assume any co-relation on tcp and udp - they are different pipes.

EDIT: For example:

1. Client `connect()` to server's public tcp interface.
2. Authentication
3. Server sends an an authentication code (cookie) to the client.
4. Client `sendto()` server's public udp interface, with the cookie.
5. Server gets `sockaddr` from `recvfrom()`.
6. Server co-relation such `sockaddr` to the revalent tcp connection, using the cookie. Optionally check/restrict the ip to prevent bull force by other.
7. That is, now you have a pair of connection - an accepted tcp socket along with `sockaddr` for udp communication.

PS. You may also want to do some encryption on the handshake, but that's out of the question's scope.

Comment: I want to use them as different pipes. But I want to communicate with the same client over these pipes, how to accomplish that other than my approach?

Comment: You should have public entrances (both tcp&udp) on the server-side, and let the client initiate the communications individually, and co-relate them with something like cookie and ip address. On the other hand, you may tell your NAT (or router) "pass thru" on the udp port range and hope there is nothing funny on your isp.

Comment: I have public entrances, for example I publicly listen on TCP port 5000, 5001 and UDP 5002. Now when a client connects I want to create a Peer object on my server and store the appropriate connection info for all channels (including the local udp port). So later I can decide how I transmit data to this client. You say I have to create a UDP handshake ontop using recv rather than transmitting local ports via a different channel? And later try to find out somehow which connection attempt belongs to which client?

Comment: Yes. you should issue `sendto()` once from `client` to `server` to initiate udp communication, so that the server have the exact contact point for udp. This also acts as udp hole punching so that packets from server can go all the way, including any isp translations, onto client machine.

Comment: What if two clients connect simultaniously via the same public IP address? I am sure this won't work properly

Comment: you will get different ports on `recvfrom()`, to differentiate them you need some kind of cookie mechanism, or have them go thru a fresh authentication cycle independent to the tcp channel.

Comment: Ok I see, thank you very much. So i really have to create way more complicated connection process.

Comment: Some further information. Your approach is logical, RTSP is indeed doing similar things. However, that also caused trouble when ISP and your router start doing port re-mapping, for RTSP they have special port arrangement and RTSP-aware NAT is actually watching the TCP communication and special handle those port. But for custom protocol you should do the complicated way.